# Matlab: error message running Quantisnp

Tags: matlab

I would like to run a program called `QuantiSNP` that used `Matlab` in its code. I am not familiar with Matlab at all. I got the below error message and no output. Any idea how to fix it? FYI, I don't have access to source code of the program....

```
??? Error using ==> chol Matrix must be positive definite.

MATLAB:posdef
```

Highly appreciate your help

Jean

Comment: Did you try with a [positive definite matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix)?

Comment: actually, the problem is that I dont know what happen within the software. I just run it with the parameters they mentioned, it works but there is no output and at the end it give me this error.. so I dont know what happened

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard trying to answer your question without seeing any code but here is some general info about the problem you are facing:

1. What you see is a Matlab error message. I assume QuantiSNP is a compiled Matlab program so you probably can't debug it. In short it says that at some point the program is trying to calculate the Cholesky factorization using `chol()` function, but the matrix inside is not positive definite. Most of the time the problem happens because the matrix is actually zero, which in turn is [potentially] caused by an invalid input parameter
2. Check to see if the parameters you are using (1) are valid and (2) match your environment. If there is an input CSV or TXT file, make sure the path is correct. Make sure numbers make sense. Are there any zeros or extra lines somewhere that should not be there?
3. Depending on which version of `QuantiSNP` you have, you may have access to the `--verbose` switch. Add `--verbose` to the end of your command (for example `quantisnp2.exe firstparam secondparam --verbose`) to see some messages on the screen as the program runs through the data. See if you can figure out where it's failing and if it's related to your input parameters.

Take a look the [QuantiSNP how-to page](https://sites.google.com/site/quantisnp/howto) to make sure you understand the required parameters and the formatting of the input file.

Comment: Thank you very much Bee for comprehensive reply and your time... I will apply what you mentione

Comment: Thank you very much Bee.. as you suggested I checked everything and the problem was Input file that was not exactly as software needed....now it is running and working... Thanks again for your time and great suggestion!